# Mail a message to each person in a range (row)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, email

I Would like to ask assistance as to how I can change Ron de Bruins code from column to row (e.g. row 1 contains name; row 2 email; row 3 reflects either yes or no).

```
Sub Test1()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Working in Office 2000-2016
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value) = "yes" Then

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Reminder"
            .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                  & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Please contact us to discuss bringing " & _
                    "your account up to date"
            'You can add files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Send  'Or use Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell
cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this...

```
Sub Test1()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Working in Office 2000-2016
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim Rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each Rng In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas
    If Rng.cell(2).Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       LCase(Rng.Cells(3).Value) = "yes" Then

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = Rng.cell(2).Value
            .Subject = "Reminder"
            .Body = "Dear " & Rng.cell(1).Value _
                  & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Please contact us to discuss bringing " & _
                    "your account up to date"
            'You can add files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Send  'Or use Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next Rng
cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The code above assumes that say B1=blank, B2=Name, B3=Email address, B4=Yes/No and B5=Blank. You may have various set of records in the same order in column B.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Suppose Row 18 (H18:AE18) contains the email address (derived by Row 19 {name} & "@yahoo.com"), and the "yes" or blank sign is in row 20, is this still applicable given I changed column("B") to "H"?

Comment: The code is looping through the group of cells in SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas in just one column. So it will work for column H as well if the data meets the criteria I mentioned below the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that names and emails are in rows 1 and 2, one person per column, then this modification should do:

```
For Each cell In Rows(2).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And LCase(cell.offset(1).Value) = "yes" Then
        ' ....
        .To = cell.Value
        .Body = "Dear " & cell.offset(-1).Value
        ' ...
```

Comment: Suppose im using a formula that returns "yes" or "" (space), does this formula affects the value = "yes"? like, will it literally consider "yes" as the value? I already tried changing the code, it's not showing any error probably because of the clean up, but i still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @MarkSy if the `"yes"` in the third row is the result of a formula, it doesn't matter, because we're taking the `.Value`. However the "yes" should be clean of extra spaces (Trimmed).

Comment: Cool. I think we got the codes right, but is not working for some reason. mind if i send you the file please? thank you very much